# How to set a folder inside an apache document to the correct permission? 

Tags: permissions, apache2

When i try to get to some apache2 folder it gives me

**You don't have permission ...**

How to give the folder and the files full permission of usage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chmod -R 755 /path/to/folder`

Apache document root are on `/var/www`. If you have set the path to something else give the similar path .i.e I usually set my document root to `$HOME/public_html`.

See [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) for more information.